# Objects of interface, but constraint on type implementing the interface

Tags: c#, generics, constraints

I've a generic method with a constraint like below:

```
private string GetResult<T>(T myObject) where T : IDoSomething<T>
{
......
}
```

Now, the problem is that the `IDoSomething` is implemented by the classes and not by classes interface and moreover the objects are always created using the interface as their type and not the class like:

```
IClassA myObject = new ClassA();
```

So, whenever the generic method is called, a cast must be made on `myObject` to forward it as a parameter.

Is there a way to avoid the cast and make the code work? (except the option of inheriting `IDoSomething` in `IClassA`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**No**, there's no way to avoid the cast in the way that you're doing it.

If you don't want `IDoSomething<T>` and `IClassA` to be related by extension and you don't want to use a variable typed with the concrete class, then there isn't any information for the compiler to use to infer that your object implements the right interface for the method without using a cast.

Answer (score 5):

No, I don't think you can avoid the cast, since the interface `IClassA` is not related in any way to `IDoSomething`.

Just the fact that some class that implements one interface also happens to implement another interface doesn't make the two interfaces compatible.

Even the assignment of a `IClassA` object back to a `ClassA` variable requires a explicit cast.

Answer (score 0):

It depends. Are you just trying to get T? In that case, you could do:

`private static string GetResult<T>(IDoSomething<T> myObject) {}`

Then `T` will be inferred correctly from the interface (since `IClassFoo` will always inherit from it) and you won't have to cast.

If you want to pass it as `T`, though AND not have to cast it, then you're out of luck, there's not a relationship you can exploit.